# How to change the color of stdout content?

Tags: command-line, bash, colors

I need to change the output color of stdout in terminal, That means I need to
show the outputs in colored contents.

For that I have tried like this.

```
      Bhuvanesh: May$ tput setaf 3 ; ls 
       Bhuvanesh: May$ tput setaf 3 ; cat file
```

The above show the output in color, So I put that into my `.bashrc` file But it will not like what I expected.

How Can I do that???Please explain

Answer (score 1):

You can use escape sequences for echo. For instancce, in the screenshot bellow you can see me set color first to red, then back to white, and source my `.mkshrc`  file, where I've placed  `$( echo -e "\033[1;31m" )` before my username @ hostname, and `$( echo -e "\033[1;37m" )` before the `*****` line, and finally  `$(echo -e "\033[1;34m" )` after $ character. In Other words my prompt is:

```
[$(batpower)]$(echo -e "\033[1;31m") _MKSH_SERGIY@UBUNTU_[$(pwd)]$(echo -e "\033[1;37m"   )
***********************************************
! $ $(echo -e "\033[1;34m")'
```

More info here: www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/colorizing.html

and here:http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/colorizing.html

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend using `tput` instead of hardcoding the terminal escapes. Also, the `$(echo -e ...)` is redundant; PS1 will already treat \e as ESC. And lastly, lines will now wrap around incorrectly because you forgot to put the terminal escapes within `\[` and `\]`. See [BashFAQ 53](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053). EDIT: missed the point this was in your .mkshrc, but this will break for bash, which is what the questioneer is using.